# what is the distribution for a chi-squired variable divided by its degrees of freedom?

Tags: statistics

Assume that Xi~N(0,1) are the standard normal variables that are mutually independent.

We know that Y=X1^2+...+Xm^2 is a chi-squired random variable with m degrees of freedom.

Let Z= Y/m=(X1^2+...+Xm^2)/m

what is the distribution for Z? Does Z have a chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. I do not know why you think so.

As you know

$$Y\sim \chi_{(m)}^2=Gamma\Bigg(\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Bigg)$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{m}Y\sim Gamma\Bigg(\frac{m}{2};\frac{m}{2}\Bigg)$$

The proofs of all these result are quite easy...if you are interested in show your attempts

---

Proof:

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{m/2}}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{m}{2}\Big)}y^{m/2-1}e^{-y/2}$$

You have to calculate the density of

$$Z=\frac{Y}{m}$$

It is immediate using the Fundamental Transformation theorem:

$$f_Z(z)=f_Y[g^{-1}(z)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dz}g^{-1}(z)\Bigg|$$

being $y=zm$ and $y'=m$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you help give the proof for me. It is very important to me. Please....

Comment: @张Fous : see my edits.

Comment: Very clear. Many thanks for your great help !